# Significance of multiplying by weight

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-system

I have been reading optimization problems in communication area where it is a common practice to maximize rate of users as below objective function:

$\hspace{28mm} \text{ Maximize } \sum_k w_k \log r_k$

here, $r_k$ is the rate of an user, $w_k$ is the weight factor for every user. Weight factor may be decided on any specific criteria such as: users availability, distance from base station etc. Now I do understand that taking log makes it a convex optimization and ensures fair proportion among users but I cant understand how the weight factor is helping to maximize the rate individual users.

So my question is, why weight factor is used in the above equation and how it is helping each user to achieve a higher rate.

Comment: You are talking about $r_k$ as the rate of user k, but in the objective function you don´t have a variable $r_k$. Do you have a typo ?

Comment: In general not the rate of an individual user gets maximized, but the sum of the weighted rate of the users gets maximized. I think it would be helpful, if you say how the rate $r_k$ is defined.